# In a <div> show the key value pairs for each object in an array of objects with line breaks for each

Tags: javascript, object, newline, line-breaks

I have an array of objects and I need to display the key value pairs of each object in a div or h6. I would like to format the text like:
key: value (line break here)
key: value (line break here) ...
My code so far is:

```
Index.html:
  <div class="game-history"></div>

JS:
  const gameHistoryReadable = response.games.map(item => {
    let gamesTemp = ''
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(item)) {
      gamesTemp += key + ': ' + value + '\n'
    }
    return gamesTemp
  })
  $('.game-history').text('')
  $('.game-history').text(gameHistoryReadable)
```

Display:
cells: ,,,,,,,, over: false _id: 602fa7c46bc4480017fb05fa owner: 602589d0b3d544001780bb69 createdAt: 2021-02-19T11:57:56.087Z updatedAt: 2021-02-19T11:57:56.087Z __v: 0 ,cells: ,,,,,,,, over: false _id: 602fa7f26bc4480017fb05fb owner: 602589d0b3d544001780bb69 createdAt: 2021-02-19T11:58:42.605Z updatedAt: 2021-02-19T11:58:42.605Z __v: 0 ,cells: ,,,,,,,, over: false _id: 60300f8a0d2da000170123cd owner: 602589d0b3d544001780bb69 createdAt: 2021-02-19T19:20:42.898Z updatedAt: 2021-02-19T19:20:42.898Z __v: 0 ,cells: ,,,,,,,, over: false _id: 603011220d2da000170123d9 owner: 602589d0b3d544001780bb69 createdAt: 2021-02-19T19:27:30.222Z updatedAt: 2021-02-19T19:27:30.222Z __v: 0 ,cells: ,,,,,,,, over: false _id: 603011a60d2da000170123dd owner: 602589d0b3d544001780bb69 createdAt: 2021-02-19T19:29:42.202Z updatedAt: 2021-02-19T19:29:42.202Z __v: 0 ,cells: ,,,,,,,, over: false _id: 603011aa0d2da000170123de owner: 602589d0b3d544001780bb69 createdAt: 2021-02-19T19:29:46.074Z updatedAt: 2021-02-19T19:29:46.074Z __v: 0 ,cells: ,,,,,,,, over: false _id: 603012260d2da000170123df owner: 602589d0b3d544001780bb69 createdAt: 2021-02-19T19:31:50.484Z updatedAt: 2021-02-19T19:31:50.484Z __v: 0 ,cells: ,,,,,,,, over: false _id: 603013d20d2da000170123e0 owner: 602589d0b3d544001780bb69 createdAt: 2021-02-19T19:38:58.767Z updatedAt: 2021-02-

Comment: So how should that look? Or should we guess what key is or value is? And why don't you change `\n` into `<br>` and insert it as HTML not text `.html(gameHistoryReadable)`? Also did you try changing your `game-history` div into `<pre>` element?

Answer (score 1):

Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow

Since I am not sure how the `response.games` will look like, so I am just going to assume the it looks something more or less like this, correct my if I am wrong :

```
[
  {
    "_id": "RANDOM_ID",
    "owner": "602589d0b3d544001780bb69",
    createdAt: "DATE"
  }
  ...
]
```

And also about the line break, if you are trying to render some text on the screen, you should be using a line break tag `<br />` rather then the `/n`

And one more thing, you should be using `$().html` if you are trying to inject something that are containing some HTML tag

```js
const response = {
  games: [
    {
      "_id": "602fa7c46bc4480017fb05fa",
      "owner": "602589d0b3d544001780bb69",
      "createdAt": "2021-02-19T11:57:56.087Z",
      "updatedAt": "2021-02-19T11:57:56.087Z"
    },
    {
      "_id": "602fa7f26bc4480017fb05fb",
      "owner": "602589d0b3d544001780bb69",
      "createdAt": "2021-02-19T11:58:42.605Z",
      "updatedAt": "2021-02-19T11:58:42.605Z"
    }
  ]
}

const gameHistoryReadable = response.games.map(item => {
  let gamesTemp = ''
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(item)) {
    gamesTemp += `${key}: ${value} <br />`;
  }
  return gamesTemp
})
$('.game-history').text('')
$('.game-history').html(gameHistoryReadable)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="game-history"></div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Works just like I wanted. Thank you.